# Images not loading - PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, cordova

I am programatically adding images to my html.  In Firefox, the images are loading fine.  But in android on all the devices I test on, no images will appear.  It just shows their alt in a box.

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-popup-container fade in" id="popupPhoto-popup" tabindex="0">
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupPhoto" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d" data-corners="false" class="ui-popup ui-body-d ui-overlay-shadow" aria-disabled="false" data-disabled="false" data-shadow="true" data-transition="none" data-position-to="origin">
            <!-- insert images here -->
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="ui-screen-hidden ui-popup-screen" id="popupCloseRight-screen"></div>
```

JS:

```
//shows images upon clicking part in table
function tableSelect(location){
//remove previous images
$("#popupPhoto").text("");
//if image was added or not
var boolean = false;
//splits part names
var part = $("#table"+location).text().split(" ");
//part[0] always empty
for(var i=1;i<part.length;i++){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    //so 11 works
    if(part[i] == "11"){
        part[i]="OO";
    }
    //runs through every name in imagedir to see if image exists
    for(var j=0;j<imagedir.length;j++){
        //check if single image
        if(part[i] == imagedir[j]){
            $("#popupPhoto").append($("<img>", {src: 'images/gradegeoImages/'+part[i]+'.png', "class": 'popphoto', alt: part[i] }));
            boolean = true;
            break;
        //checks if double image
        }else if(part[i].concat("1") == imagedir[j]){
            $("#popupPhoto").append($("<img>", {src: 'images/gradegeoImages/'+part[i]+'1.png', "class": 'popphoto', alt: part[i].concat("1") }));
            $("#popupPhoto").append($("<img>", {src: 'images/gradegeoImages/'+part[i]+'2.png', "class": 'popphoto', alt: part[i].concat("2") }));
            boolean = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //if no images, display "No information available"
    if(boolean == false){
        $("#popupPhoto").append($("<div>", {text: 'No information availabe for '+gradegeo+' of '+part[i]}));
    }
}
//show images
$("#popupPhoto").addClass("ui-popup-active");

}
```

Comment: did you by chance `alert()` the path your appending to make sure the path is correct? I used to have similar problems, and it turned out that the way I was handling it cause the path to be incorrect just a smidge bit. Also I found that `/` before my path (assuming the images are within the app itself) ie: `/images/gradegeoImages/imagefile.jpg` helped as well. I use appmobi though not phonegap all though one in the same thing for the most part

Comment: What do you mean by alert the path? can you give me a code example. I don't think I'm doing it right.  And I just added the `/` and it didn't do anything

Comment: well right now your putting it out as the images src location, and you can't nessisarily do a view source in that thing to see whats what, so next best thing would be to use an alert box with the path your creating for the image source, to see if its outputting correctly

Comment: alert('/images/gradegeoImages/'+part[i]+'.png'); - like this?

Comment: yea, same way your appending it to your source but just doing it in an alert to see whats actually being formed, to see if its actually right for what your trying to do overall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that when I called for my image in the image path, part[i]'s value was in capital letters, while the image names were in lowercase.  After I figured this out I felt incredibly stupid... Apparently firefox doesn't care whether your images are case sensitive or not, because they were working on there during the debugging process.